# Problemas com OpenCV(python3 e ROS)

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

eu estou usando ROS para um projeto na faculdade, mas quando vou tentar usar python 3 para chamar o opencv, ocorre esse problema
"ImportError: /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cv2.so: undefined symbol: PyCObject_Type"
 Já estou a quase uma semana tentando resolver e não consigo.

Answer (score 0):

Segundo [essa página](https://answers.ros.org/question/237613/how-to-define-ros-kinetic-to-use-python3-instead-of-python27/), não existe uma distribuição oficial do ROS pro Python 3, mas pode ser possível fazer funcionar se você compilar o ROS da fonte.